# How to correctly insert managed metadata term id using spservices updatelistitems

Tags: sharepoint-2013, spservices

I have a sharepoint 2013 site that uses a managed metadata term set for navigation. Documents can be tagged with the managed metadata so they appear in whatever category or categories is appropriate for the document. I need to allow documents to be saved as favorites. I created a custom list that saves the file name and path but I can't get the managed metadata settings to save correctly. I am using spservices.UpdateListItems via javascript and pass the ids and terms in the valuepairs property of the call like so ;#. Although the method saves the record, it either does not save the term or it saves one completely unrelated. Does anyone have any further advice on how to do this?

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: true,
    batchCmd: "New",
    listName: "UserFavorites",
    valuepairs: [["Title", title],  ["DocumentId", itemid],["AssetCategory", assetCategoriesString]],
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 
        alert(Status + " -- " + xData.responseText);      
    }
});
```

Example of the assetCategoriesString variable contents:
 
"fc8d083a-fc5e-4525-8fef-04ba982d1633;#Print Publications"

Comment: To clarify, the AssetCategory is a managed metadata custom site column I created. It is linked to the term set that drives the navigation as well as classifies the documents. It is a field on all the content types that can be uploaded.

Comment: Can anyone help with this?